# Why it's not printing the maximum score of individual player?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to use the `awk` utility to list the maximum score of individual player.

This is my `cricketer.txt` file:

```
Virat Kohli:30
Suresh Raina:90
Shikhar Dhawan:122
Virat Kohli:33
Shikhar Dhawan:39
Suresh Raina:10
Suresh Raina:44
MS Dhoni:101
MS Dhoni:33
Virat Kohli:39
Virat Kohli:93
Virat Kohli:94
Steven Smith:44
Steven Smith:32
Rohit Sharma:33
Rohit Sharma:18
Rohit Sharma:206
Steven Smith:55
```

This is my `max.awk` file:

```
awk -F ":" -v c=0 '{name[c]=$1;runs[c]=$2;c++;}
END{
i=0
j=0
while(i<NR)
{
    j=0
    k=0
    k1=0
    max=0
    while(j<NR)
    {
        if(name[i]==name[j])
        {
        cruns[k]=runs[j]
        k++
        }
        max=cruns[0]
        if(cruns[k1] > max)     
        {
            max=cruns[k1]
            k1=k1+1
        }
        j=j+1           
    }
    print name[i],max
    i=i+1
  }
}' cricketer.txt | sort | uniq > max.txt
```

This is my `max.txt` file I am getting.

```
MS Dhoni 101
Rohit Sharma 33
Shikhar Dhawan 122
Steven Smith 44
Suresh Raina 90
Virat Kohli 30
```

It looks like that it is printing only the first score of each individual player. Is the code of `max.awk` file is wrong?

Comment: The condition `if(cruns[k1] > max)` will always be false since `k1=0` and `max=cruns[0]`, so basically it is equivalent as `if(cruns[0] > cruns[0])`

Comment: So what can I do with k1? because for every individual player i will have to create an array with all his scores then I will have to set the max to first element of the array then find maximum.

Comment: A straightforward way to fix this code is to enclose your condition with a for loop, e.g. `for(k1=1; k1<length(cruns); k1++){ if(cruns[k1]>max){ max=cruns[k1] } }`. This way it can actually scan through all scores you have previously stored for a specific player. You might also need to add a `delete cruns` after `print name[i],max` to reset the array after each loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same, to get the maximum score for each cricketer :)

```
awk -F":" '{a[$1]=a[$1]>$NF?a[$1]:$NF} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sort -t: -k2rn file | awk -F':' '!seen[$1]++'
Rohit Sharma:206
Shikhar Dhawan:122
MS Dhoni:101
Virat Kohli:94
Suresh Raina:90
Steven Smith:55
```

Comment: I know that -k2rn is there for sorting but what is seen doing??

Comment: It's a very common awk idiom for only printing the the first time a value is seen. `seen[$1]` is just an array indexed by the first input field (the persons name in your case). The first time a name occurs `seen[name]` will be zero so `!seen[name]` will be 1 (i.e. true) and sothe line will be printed and then the post-increment `++` will set `seen[name]` to 1. The second and subsequent times `seen[name]` appears it has a non-zero value from the previous time it appeared and so !seen[name] is false and so the line isn't printed. It's like `uniq` but compares on a per-field basis.